# How to handle Html tags in string - when displayed in MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rally

So I'm retrieving data from the Rally web service and the description field contains html tags.

My MVC page looks like this:

```
<table width="100%" id="stories">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>TaskEstimateTotal</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var story in Model.UserStories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@story["FormattedID"]</td>
                <td>@story["Name"]</td>
                <td>@story["Description"]</td>
                <td>@story["TaskEstimateTotal"]</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

The html tags appear as text
eg:

```
<DIV>As a Marketing Analytics And Data Manager</DIV>
```

I've tried encoding and decoding it but neither of those are producing the desired response.  Encoding it will convert the `<` into `&lt;` type text.

```
<td>@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(story["Description"])</td>
```

Hopefully it's just something simple I've missed!

Unless I should be stripping out the tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<td>@Html.Raw(story["Description"])</td>
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
<td>@Html.Raw(story["Description"])</td>
```

Razor html encodes strings by default.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I needed (someone else must have posted just before you so I've accepted based on order) :)